# I need to parse text to find beginning, middle and end of a phrase, replace beginning completely, keep middle, and modify ending

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am converting DB2 SQL to Microsoft TSQL Syntax.

DB2 has a CONCAT function working completely different from TSQL that I need to convert.

Example problems...these are all legitimate syntax examples:

## Concat as function

```
CONCAT ( sample1.ColumnName, sample2.ColumnName)
```

Converts to:

```
sample1.ColumnName + sample2.ColumnName
```

## Concat as inline

```
sample1.ColumnName CONCAT sample2.ColumnName
```

Converts to

```
sample1.ColumnName + sample2.ColumnName
```

### Concat Symbol as inline

```
sample1.ColumnName || sample2.ColumnName
```

Converts to

```
sample1.ColumnName + sample2.ColumnName
```

## CONCAT as Simple Composite

```
CONCAT ( sample1.ColumnName, TRIM(sample2.ColumnName))
```

Converts to

```
sample1.ColumnName + TRIM(sample2.ColumnName)
```

## CONCAT as Conversion from %!@^#*^&*

```
CONCAT ( sample1.ColumnName, sample3.ColumnName CONCAT TRIM(sample2.ColumnName))
```

Converts to

```
sample1.ColumnName + sample3.ColumnName + TRIM(sample2.ColumnName)
```

## CONCAT as the Worse Case Scenario

```
CONCAT ( CONCAT(sample1.ColumnName, sample4.ColumnName), sample3.ColumnName CONCAT TRIM(sample2.ColumnName))
```

Converts to

```
sample1.ColumnName + sample4.ColumnName + sample3.ColumnName + TRIM(sample2.ColumnName)
```

It would be nice to have recursive regex. I can make multiple calls if only processing the outer or inner instance of the replacement pattern.

The one I'm hung up on the most is the version of `CONCAT ( value1, value2 )`
I can identify `CONCAT (`. How do I identify `value1, value2` and the correct instance of the closing `)`?
If I can do that, then I can drop `CONCAT (` and `)`. I can return `value1 + "+" + value2`.

If that scenario could be defined, I could extrapolate other formulas needed, knowing how to specify the necessary groups.

Comment: would [sqlines](https://github.com/dmtolpeko/sqlines) be any help?

Comment: I was not familiar with that library. Very cool.

It does not translate CONCAT in the online version from DB2 to MS TSQL. However, it does a great job converting TRIM() to LTRIM(RTRIM())

I'm definitely going to look into it further

Comment: Hmmm. Yes, seems to only handle your case 2: http://www.sqlines.com/db2-to-sql-server#built-in-sql-functions ; but ms page says concat function exists: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 so maybe only your case 2 and 3 need to be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I feel that I would approach it the same way as you have described in your title.  First, remove everything off the front of your string and also any closing parenthesis that are not followed by another closing parenthesis.  I would match the following and replace with nothing:

```
^CONCAT.*CONCAT\s*\(    |    ^Concat (?:Symbol )?as inline    |    \)(?!\))
```

Then, do a second replace to look for commas, the string `CONCAT` or a set of double vertical pipes `||` and replace it with a plus sign:

```
\s*(?:    ,    |    CONCAT    |    \|\|    )\s*
```

[Here is a demo in PHP](https://ideone.com/Ubg2G6)

Comment: That's a big help and gets me started.

It's the compound scenarios that get me.

Comment: Same issue with CONCAT (CONCAT(String1, string2), String3)

I need to make sure it is case insensitive, and that it ignores white space before and after the () function colsures.

I may have enough from your example already to figure out the rest.

Thanks loads for the response.

Comment: I just looked at your PHP example. It appears to do everything I want. I should be able to translate this to work with C# Regex.

THANKS LOADS!!!

BTW, all the white space...is that to make the regex more readable? It doesn't do anything does it?

Comment: Ok! I can't get over how really cool your solution is, and it really makes sense. I was trying to do everything in one pass  making it much harder. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: I am so close. Request was re-formatted causing confusion

SELECT CONCAT (T1.C1, T1.C2 CONCAT T1.C3) FROM T1

Converts to: 

SELECT T1.C1 + T1.C2 + T1.C3 FROM T1

So, I still need to return SELECT before CONCAT and FROM T1 after close parentheses

Comment: I added a third regex in front of the other two that will address this.  [Here's a link to the revised demo](https://ideone.com/Z6gPRN).  All I'm really doing in this one is removing the `CONCAT` following a `SELECT` and the closing parenthesis before a `FROM`.

Comment: The third regex was the key to the whole problem for me. Once I figured out how to convert the python syntax to c# regex, this gives me a foundation to fix this, and many other conversion issues such as replace TRIM() with LTRIM(RTRIM()).

Your's is the most powerful and meaningful answer to my problem space simply because the concept can be applied to many different scenarios.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

db2 concat to other.

do while locate('Concat(', mystring) = 0
Convert conat(blah , blah ) to blah || blah 
loop

Make sure it still works on db2 and you haven't broke anything.

convert || to +

Comment: That works quite nicely. It has a some features that help a lot and one shortcoming.

1) It handles Case if not set to case sensitive character set
2) It can handle white space between Concat and (
3) It doesn't help you identify the matching close parenthesis like regex can, which must be removed
4) I don't have DB2, only the DB2 query definition I need to convert to run on TSQL syntax

Comment: Definitely going to check out the book recommendation :-)

Comment: Yep that's pseudo code how you implement is on dev.  having a statement that still works for testing  priceless